# Move CALayer leaves behind original 'after-image'

Tags: animation, calayer

**Environment:** Xcode 5.0.2/iOS 7

**Goal:** to merely move a layer from point 'A' to point 'B'.

**Problem:** the 'move' acts like a 'copy'.

I've tried 2 move paradigms: 
1) set the layer's position; and 
 
2):

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.fromValue = [layer valueForKey:@"position"];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
layer.position = point;
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

**Note:** The CALayer @ destination is accessible and am able to remove it from its container layer.

      The CALayer @ origin apparently is orphaned.

**Question:** what would cause this 'move' to act as a 'copy'? 

Any remedy?

***Weird Note:*** this code works correctly within a different UIViewController's view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stemmed from setting up the CALayers within UIViewController`s

 - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {} <-- don't setup CALayers here!

rather than the *correct*:

- (void)viewDidLoad {}  <-- preferred spot.

Creating CALayers within viewdidLayoutSubviews{} causes any position change to COPY vs MOVE.

However, creating CALayers within viewDidLoad{} behaves correctly: any position change is a MOVE.

Seems like a bug to me.